# iOS MVC - Where does data type conversion take place?

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I'm learning MVC while building an iPhone application and in wondering where data type conversion belongs? For example, I have a uitextfield that accepts a duration from the user in the form "12:59" (minutes : seconds). This has to be convert to seconds represented as an integer.

So my question is, should the model object accept the string, do the conversion and store it? Should the UIViewController handle the conversion to and from the model and view? Or should I have some sort of formatter object attached to the text field to handle this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to MVC:

- view - UITextField
- model - any information or data
- controller - converter/formatter, UIViewController

On the real life:
I advise you to unite data converter/formatter and UIViewController but if you need to use this code in other classes it's good to write separated class like DataConverter

Comment: I was going to say the same. The "best practise" way of doing this is to create a class (separate from your model and controller) that does the formatting from you. A bit like NSDateFormatter but your own version.

Answer (score 1):

**UIViewController** this holds all the **logic** so "12.59" must be converted as seconds in your textview delegate method

Answer (score 0):

Have the delegates of the `UITextField` in your controller, the conversion shall take place in the  controller ideally.